# Not inserting HTTP POST data into two separate tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, http-post

I am creating a tracking application to keep track of some server and their build info. I want the user to fill out one single form that then performs a INSERT into two separate tables. Here is my code, but it only populates the "Server" table and not the "System_Build_Information" table. I have tried also changing the Bindings and even leaving them out all together. This code by the way is from my Server controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Server_Name,Server_Role,Server_OS")] Server server, [Bind(Include = "Model")] System_Build_Information sys)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Servers.Add(server);
        db.System_Build_Information.Add(sys);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Server_Role = new SelectList(db.Server_Roles, "Id", "Server_Role", server.Server_Role);
    ViewBag.Server_OS = new SelectList(db.Operating_System, "Id", "Operating System", server.Server_OS);
    string[] environments = new string[] { "Virtual", "Physical" };
    ViewBag.Environments = new SelectList(environments);
    return View(server);
}
```

Comment: code looks ok. have you try to debug? do you have data in server and sys variapal on post? is ModelState.IsValid = true?

Comment: ModelSate is valid, but nothing in sys variable. Now I am kind of new to entity framework, but I only see one model defined in my view. Tried adding another model but it crashed saying only one model be defined.

Comment: there is no way to define 2 models, you should use ViewData or ViewBag for this model or - better - create wrapper View model that contains 2 models.

Comment: you shouldn't use business model classes (EF models) on your MVC or Web API actions as parameters, you should introduce viewmodel or dto classes, then do a mapping between VM and Business model and then save business entities into db via EF

Comment: introduce a VM class that holds your two classes, Bind introduces noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the default model binder is not able to bind to the two classes that you have passed (and the `Bind()` statements may also be interfering).  If you need to have information from two models placed into a view and POSTed back, create a new view model class that contains the models for both of those classes.

```
public class ServerInfoViewModel{
    public Server ServerInfo {get;set;}

    public System_Build_Information SystemBuildInfo {get;set;}
}
```

Now, send this view model back and forth to your view.

```
@model namespace.ServerInfoViewModel
```

and to use the properties in your form

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ServerInfo.Type)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.SystemBuildInfo.SomeField)
```

Lastly, you would need to update your POST action method to bind the new view model

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ServerInfoViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Servers.Add(model.ServerInfo);
        db.System_Build_Information.Add(model.SystemBuildInfo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Server_Role = new SelectList(db.Server_Roles, "Id", "Server_Role", server.Server_Role);
    ViewBag.Server_OS = new SelectList(db.Operating_System, "Id", "Operating System", server.Server_OS);
    string[] environments = new string[] { "Virtual", "Physical" };
    ViewBag.Environments = new SelectList(environments);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Creating a View Model Class and removing the Binds worked. Thanks!